# PNG file size increases when saving to storage

Tags: java, android-studio, png, filesize

I had a png drawable in my android project which has a size of **36.98kb**, I'm saving this picture to the user device in the cache directory.

this is my code

```
File wmImg = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "WmImg.png");
            if (!wmImg.exists()) {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(wmImg);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.watermark);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            }
```

the file is saved successfully but the image size is increased to **264kb**. It's a huge difference between the original image and the saved image. why is this happening?

How to save the png file to android without increasing the size?

please any help or suggestion...

Comment: Why do you decode and compress the image in the first place? Why don't you just [copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) it?

Comment: But how to copy from Android drawable to storage?